# Find value from the for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, max

```
<?php
function factorial($number)
{
    if ($number < 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return ($number * factorial($number-1));
    }
}

function poisson($occurrence,$chance)
{
    $e = exp(1);

    $a = pow($e, (-1 * $chance));
    $b = pow($chance,$occurrence);
    $c = factorial($occurrence);

    return $a * $b / $c;
}

$x = 2.5;
$y = 1.5;
$calAll = array();
for($z = 0 ; $z <= 9 ; $z++) {
    array_push($calAll,
                (poisson($z,$x) * poisson(0,$y))*100,
                (poisson($z,$x) * poisson(1,$y))*100,
                (poisson($z,$x) * poisson(2,$y))*100
            );
}
$value = max($calAll);
$key = array_search($value, $calAll);
print_r($calAll) . "\n";
echo "max =",$value , " key =",$key . "\n";;
?>
```

it is possible to find $z and the number 0,1 or 2 from the max of the returned array ?
I used excel to perform this action and i found that for max=8.5854557290941 the $z is 2 and number 1 how to achieve this in php ?

Comment: Where's the `while` loop?

Comment: What is `$z`? What do you need?

Comment: @chris85 sorry for loop i updated the title

Comment: @Aaron i want to find the $z from the loop it is between the 0 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array elements are pushed in groups of 3 for each value of `$z`, `$z` is the integer part of the index divided by 3, and `$occurrence` is the remainder.

```
$z = floor($key, 3);
$occurrence = $key % 3;
```